# Admin Panel crashing - after theme installation

Tags: magento-2.0.2

I have downloaded and installed a magento2 theme. I enabled it under **Stores>Configuration>Design**.

```
As soon as I want to flush the cache it gives me the following error:

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1072691483201
```

And I can't log into the admin panel till I uninstall the files "theme.xml", "composer.json" and "registration.php" of the installed theme.
The store also gives the same error as soon as the theme is installed.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Could you please post the content of `var/report/1072691483201`?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove maintenance.flag file from your root folder, also remove cache and session folder which inside the var.